# Not able to build the package using phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am not able to build the package via Phonegap build.

Some traces from the log are:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/m1/wl3zc68x40z6cn12m764qkf80000gn/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Rit-generated-files.hmap -I/project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Rit-own-target-headers.hmap -I/project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Rit-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/MojeUPC-project-headers.hmap -I/project/build/include -I/project/build/usr/local/lib/include -I/project/build/UninstalledProducts/include -I/project/build/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include -I/project/build -I/project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/DerivedSources -F/project/build -include /var/folders/m1/wl3zc68x40z6cn12m764qkf80000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.1-7B91b/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Rit-Prefix-dsittitpughsecbtjzuxadbqcyki/Rit-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVFileTransfer.d --serialize-diagnostics /project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVFileTransfer.dia -c /project/Rit/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m -o /project/build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVFileTransfer.o
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC build/Rit.build/Release-iphoneos/Rit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PushPlugin.o Rit/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin/PushPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)

Please provide any support, if possible.

Regards
Riten

Comment: try to remove and add push plugin again..

Comment: I have solved my problem by removing the push-plugin from the config.xml